# K8S организация БД

Tags: kubernetes

У Меня есть идея организации хранения БД на одном контейнере, а выполнять развёртку самих сервисов в других контейнерах, но не совсем понимаю насколько эта правильная организация подов. Если проводить аналогию с обычной организацией, мол сервер БД на одном сервере, а сам условный сервер IIS на другом сервере, то насколько правильно это для организации Kubernetus. То есть, есть (Как пример) 5 подов, для каждого из подов внутри есть сервис требующий свою БД и есть 1 под с mySQL сервером на борту. Стоит ли все сервисы подсоединять к этому серверу БД или для каждого сервиса требуется свой сервер БД?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А тут первый вопрос к самому приложению. Если каждому экземпляру сервиса нужна своя БД то и класть ее вместе с сервисом (правда не ясно что при этом с хранением состояния БД при перезапусках, стейтфул для каждого экземпляра отдельно как то странно смотреться будет, но если таковы требования кода, значит придется).

А если несколько экземпляров (одного сервиса) работают с общей БД (чаще всего оно так и есть), то БД надо разворачивать отдельно, что бы она как минимум не перезапускалась вместе с сервисами.

Если речь идет именно про независимые сервисы, у каждого из которых собственная БД, которая общая между экземплярами одного сервиса, то под каждый сервис разворачивать отдельную БД, отдельным pod. Что бы в случае проблем с производительностью можно было легко перенести их на разные ноды и что бы перегрузка БД запросами одним сервисом не влияли на другие сервисы.

Comment: Сервисы разные.